# Find probability of new point from R histogram

Tags: r, histogram

Based on this sample data, I built a histogram as follows:

```
df = rnorm(100)
h = hist (df, plot = FALSE)
h$counts = h$counts/sum(h$counts)
```

Now, assume I want to check the probability of a `new_point` to be drawn from this histogram (i.e., get the probability of the interval (histogram `breaks`) the `new_point` belongs to). How can I do it?

Comment: `(h$density/sum(h$density))[findInterval(new_point, h$breaks)]` or `(h$counts/sum(h$counts))[findInterval(new_point, h$breaks)]`